# How to distribute the load of Rails app between AWS servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, scale

I want to distribute the load of few servers on AWS and my own home server, link DBs between them and make backup.
I use REE, nginx and passenger.
What are the ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up a load balancer is a common way to solve this. All requests go to the load balancer, which acts as a proxy and sends the request on to one of the nodes you want to distribute load for.

If you want to set this up yourself I understand it is straight forward to spin up a small EC2  (or any other VPS) instance using nginx or similar.

If you want a turn-key solution Amazon offers [Elastic Load Balancing](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/). Other ready-to-go solutions include Rackspace's Cloud Load Balancers. Probably best to go with Amazon since their ELB will have low latency connection to your EC2 nodes.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! What instruments you could offer in case i set up myself? And how to synchronize the DBs between servers?